# How to float image in div with centered text and correct background

Tags: html, css

This is what my header bar currently looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYZkc.png

However, I want the text to be centered horizontally and have the image all the way to the left.

When I tried adding float: left to the image's css, it completely messed it up, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PEni.png

As you can see, the title is not aligned horizontally or vertically, and the bar doesn't stretch to accommodate the image.

HTML:

```
<div class="EA-header-bar">
    <img src="~/Images/EA Icons/YoungDriver_white.png" class="EA-header-image" />
    <p class="EA-header-text">
        <b>YOUNG DRIVERS</b>
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.EA-header-bar {
    background-color: rgb(206,33,39);
    text-align: center;
}

.EA-header-image {
    margin: 1%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    height:150px;
    float: left;
}

.EA-header-text {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 6vmin;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font: bolder;
    font-family: kalinga;
}
```

Comment: You could try using image as a div's background image while keeping text centered.. To center text add margin: 0 auto; and set width of text less than container.. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing this kind of positioning work try to use flexbox, coding is fast and nifty. Also put tags like `<img>`,`<p>` or related inline tags inside `<div>` just to look pro, but those are just recomendations always look for ways to improve your css.

```css
.EA-header-bar {
    display: flex;
    background-color: rgb(206,33,39);
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.EA-col-img {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.EA-col-txt {
  flex:1
}
.EA-header-image {
    height:150px;
}

.EA-header-text {
    color: white;
    font-size: 6vmin;
    font: bolder;
    font-family: kalinga;
}
```

```html
<div class="EA-header-bar">
    <div class="EA-col-img">
          <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/75/75804.svg" class="EA-header-image" />

    </div>
    <div class="EA-col-txt">
      <p class="EA-header-text">
        <b>YOUNG DRIVERS</b>
    </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Another example using absolute positionining

I think this one is more accured to your needs

```css
.EA-header-bar {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    background-color: rgb(206,33,39);
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.EA-col-img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5vw;
}
.EA-col-txt {
  flex:1
}
.EA-header-image {
    height:20vh;
}

.EA-header-text {
    color: white;
    font-size: 6vmin;
    font: bolder;
    font-family: kalinga;
}
```

```html
<div class="EA-header-bar">
    <div class="EA-col-img">
          <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/75/75804.svg" class="EA-header-image" />

    </div>
    <div class="EA-col-txt">
      <p class="EA-header-text">
        <b>YOUNG DRIVERS</b>
    </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it's almost perfect. However, using the 2nd one, there is still a problem where the bar won't adjust its height to account for the image. (Sorry it took me so long to respond, I hadn't been at work)